# аббревиатура

Tags: этимология

Слово "аббревиатура" звучит загадочно и непривычно для русского уха. А каково его происхождение?  *Скульптура*, *клавиатура* из того же ряда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

От итал. abbreviatura «сокращение», от гл. abbreviare «сокращать», из лат. abbreviare «сокращать», далее из ad «к, на» + brevis «короткий» (восходит к праиндоевр. *mregh-wi- «короткий»).